# GWT object serialization

Tags: java, mysql, gwt, serializable

I'm trying to return an arrayList from my mysql database to use in a GWT cellList, but I'm running into a serialization issue.

> Type 'com.cbs.ioma.client.Order' was not included in the set of
>   types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class
>   object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not
>   be serialized.: instance = Order [orderNumber=1001, orderer=test,
>   assembler=1, dateCompleted=1969-12-31, dateSubmitted=1969-12-31,
>   notes=rer, isComplete=false, type=erer]

I have a class Order, but when i try and change it to

> `public class Order implements java.io.Serializable`

the program crashes and no error is message is displayed. I don't know a lot about serialization inside of GWT so how would I go about serializing a class to use in GWT? I have the correct function names in the service and serviceAync class I believe. thanks.

Edit: I'll add a little more here. I tried changing the order class to implement isSerializable and then I get this error

> 12:55:49.793 [ERROR] [ioma] Uncaught exception escaped
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.cbs.ioma.client.Order cannot be cast
>   to java.lang.String
>       at com.google.gwt.text.shared.SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer.render(SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer.java:1)
>       at com.google.gwt.cell.client.AbstractSafeHtmlCell.render(AbstractSafeHtmlCell.java:80)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellList.renderRowValues(CellList.java:527)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.AbstractHasData$View.renderRowValues(AbstractHasData.java:337)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.AbstractHasData$View.replaceAllChildren(AbstractHasData.java:239)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.HasDataPresenter.resolvePendingState(HasDataPresenter.java:1351)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.HasDataPresenter.access$3(HasDataPresenter.java:1062)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.HasDataPresenter$2.execute(HasDataPresenter.java:984)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Task$.executeScheduled$(SchedulerImpl.java:50)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.runScheduledTasks(SchedulerImpl.java:228)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.flushFinallyCommands(SchedulerImpl.java:327)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.exit(Impl.java:266)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:257)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I'm not sure why it wants to cast a order to a string. I feel there is something fundamental about serialization I'm missing here, can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you have .gwt.xml file @ com/cbs/ioma/ folder? is that included in your jar along with the .java files for com.cbs.ioma.client.Order?

Comment: I have the xml file inside of the WAR file if that is what you are referring to. Do I need a second one? and my order.java is inside com.cbs.ioma.client

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement [IsSerializable](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/IsSerializable.html) instead of Serializable. But in general your code should work. This error occurring sometimes (during debug) but in most cases it works after recompile.

Comment: Yes you should implement gwt rpc's  isSerializable instead java serializable.

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow your data types to be transferred from/to client to/from server using `GWT-RPC`, you need to mark them as *serializable* by implementing either the `IsSerializable` or `Serializable` interface. You also have to ensure the serializability of the class fields (except final/transient fields, which will not be serialized at all) and the presence of a default zero-arg constructor (or none at all).

EDIT: Serialization of final fields is actually under [review](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1054).

If, for some reason, you cannot meet those requirements, you need to use `DTO`s filled with your object data, in order to transport them to/from the client/server. Or you can try to implement your own [custom serializer](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideCustomSerialization) for that class.

Take a look at the [docs for GWT serialization](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideSerializableTypes) and to the [java.io.Serializable support](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_Server#Does_the_GWT_RPC_system_support_the_use_of_java.io.Serializable) if you want. And also clean all *.gwt.rpc files in your war dir, to force the re-creaton of the serialization policy.